# How to make Python Kivy webview app with navigation button and open external link in browser?

Tags: android, python, android-webview, kivy

I am trying to make an android app for a website with Python Kivy. I am using 2nd code from [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Android-native-embedded-browser). 1) I want all external links to open in device browser and 2)  Back button minimizes the app instead of exiting.
 Please suggest the changes I should make. Thanks

For 1st problem, there are some solutions of using if_else with INTENT, but all are in Java and not Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To open a link with the device's browser you should use:

   ```
   import webbrowser    
   webbrowser.open(link)
   ```
2. To pause the app instead of exit it, you should add this method to your App Class:

   ```
   def on_pause(self):
       return True
   ```

Comment: do I have to add `requirements=webbrowser` in p4a build command?

Comment: No, you do not.

Comment: 1st one did not work for me. 2nd one (pause issue) worked. I will add more details for 1st issue when I get back to making the app